# VS Codespaces bash shell failed to initiate

Tags: bash, shell, codespaces

I'm using VS codespaces to complete the current CS50X course.
I've been getting on very well with it but have hit a snag where the Terminal doesn't seem to be loading correctly. I think i'm missing a couple of options at the top of the Terminal section - Debug and Port. I'm trying to complete the Finance section of the course which involves connecting to a development server but when i try i get the following erroe message:
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4","title":"Not Found","status":404,"traceId":"00-76b8a3e0c4eaccf805373ec05e5ec917-dccabf0efd4cf681-00"}

I've tried to Google what might be going on but i'm very new to programming and don't understand a lot of what i'm reading!!
I did notice that the shell has failed to initiate, but again, i don't really know what that means.
I've tried re-loading the window repeatedly but still get the same situation.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!!

Comment: More infomation are needed. Try to show more output, tell us what you expected and what it did. Check out https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4385980-ask-a-question

Comment: This seems to me a question about configuring _Visual Studio Codespaces_, and not about programming.  Unless you can reproduce the bash error outside the context of Visual Studio, I suggest that you post the problem (maybe with a screenshot of your Visual Studio configuration) at [su].